# Inkscape: Add a 180deg arc to a rectangele

Tags: inkscape

I'd like to add a 180 degree arc to the top of a rectangle and remove the internal lines to create a single shape (best described as a 'finger' shape).

I've managed to create both shapes, but lining them up is proving tricky and then selecting Path/Union seems to only remove portions of the common lines.

I'd welcome some advice on the bet way to go about doing this to help expedite my workflow and contain the swearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the snaps to points ON and snap to grid OFF.

[image]

1. Draw a rectangle
2. Draw a circle. Hold Ctrl+Shift to start from the midpoint. Start at the middle of the top side of the rectangle. See the snapping indications (one is visible)
3. Check the size and the position. Inkscape shows the object widths. Use high zoom, too. When ready, make the union.

If you do not need exact circular roundness, only continuity and smooth curve, be fast and add the curvature to the rectangle.

- select the rectangle, goto Path > Object to Path to make a freely editable curve
- take the Node tool, double-click the midpoint of the top side of the rectangle to create a new node. Drag it upwards.
- click the new node holding Ctrl. The handles appear. Drag them to good curvature.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @user287001 - I enabled "Snap midpoints of line segments" to grab the midpoint of the top of my rectangle and that made it east to draw the circle correctly.  Your option 1 worked accurately and quickly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is to draw a rectangle, round the corners, add another rectangle to chop off the bottom, by selecting both shapes and use *Path > Difference* (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: This makes sense, but it makes getting exact measurements tricky.  Getting the curved edges to a perfect circle, then getting the bottom section to intersect at just the right point means I'd need to add quite a few construction / guide lines too.